# how to get the value of a key from json which matches the user input from dropdown in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have json in the following format.

```
  [{"custId":7,"emailId":"raju.allen1888@gmail.com","facebookId":"","twitterId":"","mobilePhone":"","landPhone":"","firstName":"Allen","lastName":""},{"custId":8,"emailId":"raju@gmail.com","facebookId":"","twitterId":"","mobilePhone":"","landPhone":"","firstName":"Emanuel","lastName":""}]
```

i have a dropdown list with all the keys, if i choose a key, for e.g emailId, i need to get the emailId from the json.

it works fine when i give like this,

```
      for(i in data){
       alert(data[i].emailId);
      }
```

when i get the value from the dropdown in a variable and try to use it like the following its giving me error as undefined.

```
     var key = $('#dropdownvalue').val(); //emailId as value from the dropdown

     for(i in data){
       alert(data[i].key);
      }
```

how to solve this, to select the value for the key selected through dropdown.

Comment: Note, what you have is NOT a JSON (at least if you can iterate through it!) but a JavaScript array object, containing other JS objects. See the JSON tag wiki for the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to access the property with a dynamic name :

```
alert(data[i][key]);
```

This means go to the object `data[i]` and access a property whose name is the string value of what's contained in `key`